# cocoa release nswindowcontroller

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I am loading a window with it's controller from a window nib file. The window has a "release when closed" option enabled. How could i release the controller as soon as the window closes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the window controller subscribe to window close notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowWillClose:) name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification object:window];
```

and in `windowWillClose:` method write code to release your window controller.

Comment: Sorry, i thought this question wasn't posted ... got a duplicate now. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your `windowWillClose:` code don't forget that you'll need to `removeObserver:` or your controller will never be released because the NSNotificationCenter has retained it.