# Closing Window and Releasing NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, osx-mountain-lion, nswindowcontroller

I have a relatively-lengthy task.  So I bring up a separate window (**NSWindowController**) from **AppDelegate** to show progress.  It goes like

```
//AppDelegate.m
if (self.progresswindow == nil) {
    self.progresswindow = [[ProgressController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"ProgressController"];
}

[progresswindow showWindow:self];
//[[progresswindow window] setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
[NSApp runModalForWindow:progresswindow.window];
```

When a task is complete, the progress window will close itself.

```
//ProgressController.m
[NSApp stopModal];
[self close];
```

It works fine.  But when I click on a button to start another session of a task with the same window, the application won't run a task although it opens.  It appears that the last instance hasn't be released.  The progress window has the following lines.

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"Hey!");
}
```

And NSLog won't be called for the 2nd time.  I wonder what I'm doing wrong?  Calling **setReleasedWhenClosed** from AppDelegate has no effect.  I have the **Release When Closed** checkbox enabled, anyway.  I read something like I need to observe **NSWindowWillCloseNotification** the progress window in a [different topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538300/cocoa-release-nswindowcontroller) so that I can release it when it closes.  But I'm using **ARC**.  So I can't manually release it, can I?  Meanwhile, if I open Apple's sample (**TableViewPlayground**), it seems that they use this notification.  Furthermore, I've read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648536/how-to-close-a-window-unload-a-nib) and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111790/display-window-again-after-closing-it-and-setting-focus).  But I don't know what the problem is.

I appreciate any advice.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release the Progress-Window-Controller.

Comment: self.progressWindow(Controller) holds the window controller. the window controller holds it window. (On nibs it is a little bit more complex because of legacy reasons, but for now.)
The next time you enter the action, you will reuse the existing window controller and this will use the existing window. If you do not want this behaviour, set the property of the delegate to nil, so there will be a new instance of the window controller (and its window) next time.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  Like progresswindow = nil; ?  This line has solved the problem by accident.

Comment: probably self.progresswindow = nil, but Yes.